# How to set the field values in namedTuple on Python?

Tags: python-3.7, namedtuple

In my pytest (python 3.7.4), I have test method which define and set the values for the fields of `namedtuple`. But I do not actually see any values set in to the field though I set the values in my code.

```
def test_TapVisaCardOnTheReader(Process):
    ResponseResults = namedtuple('ResponseResults',['STATUS', 'ISO8583', 'TOKEN', 'ICC_PUBLIC_KEY'])
    ResponseResults('01', True, True, True)
    TapResponseResults=Process.TappingPaymentCardOntheReader(' Visa-Card ')
    assert ((ResponseResults.STATUS == TapResponseResults.STATUS) and (
            ResponseResults.ISO8583 == TapResponseResults.ISO8583) and (
                    ResponseResults.TOKEN == TapResponseResults.TOKEN) and (
                    ResponseResults.ICC_PUBLIC_KEY == TapResponseResults.ICC_PUBLIC_KEY))
```

Please check the following debug output window where I do not see any values have been set.

[image: OutputWindow]
Also I have one more question about comparison of `namedtuple` fields, In my code I had to compare every single filed of `namedtuple` ,instead is there any way to compare all the fields of `namedtuple` at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part of the code, you create the ResponseResults object without saving it:

```
ResponseResults = namedtuple('ResponseResults',['STATUS', 'ISO8583', 'TOKEN', 'ICC_PUBLIC_KEY'])
ResponseResults('01', True, True, True)
```

What you actually want is:

```
ResponseResults = namedtuple('ResponseResults',['STATUS', 'ISO8583', 'TOKEN', 'ICC_PUBLIC_KEY'])
response_results = ResponseResults('01', True, True, True)
# continue with response_results...
```

Edit: Regarding your second question: if you want to compare all fields of two namedtuples directly, you can use the `==` operator:

```
from collections import namedtuple

ResponseResults = namedtuple('ResponseResults',['STATUS', 'ISO8583', 'TOKEN', 'ICC_PUBLIC_KEY'])
response_results = ResponseResults('01', True, True, True)
response_results_2 = ResponseResults('01', True, True, True)
response_results_3 = ResponseResults('01', True, True, False)

response_results == response_results_2 # this is True
response_results == response_results_3 # this is False
```

Comment: @Raj See also my edit to answer your second question.